# Workaround for running tomcat with IntelliJ, maybe a script to push to tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

what kind of workarounds would you guys suggest if I want to run a spring mvc project in intellij (free version) and run it on tomcat?

How about a script to push compiled files to a running instance of tomcat?

how would this work?

Answer (score 2):

Create an ant script that builds the contents of your war to a folder in your project like `build/war` for example then create a `my-app.xml` file in `conf\Catalina\localhost` with contents like this:

```
<Context path="my-app" reloadable="true" docBase="C:\workspace\[projectname]\build\war" workDir="C:\workspace\[projectname]\work" >
    <Logger className="org.apache.catalina.logger.SystemOutLogger" verbosity="4" timestamp="true"/>
</Context>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should look into maven and it's deployment support and/or it's tomcat runtime support. You could also whip up a script using Ant, Groovy, Ruby or some other scripting language to push your files to the deployment directory.

I guess lastly you could use an IDE that does not tie your hands like that, or give in and pay JetBrain$.

Good luck.

Comment: A much better approach is to replace Tomcat with Jetty for development purposes :) You can even debug it perfectly.

Comment: I would second that as well, and Jetty is also runnable via a maven plugin. I stuck with Tomcat here in case Blankman has a specific need for it.